# Всплывающее окно при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь реализовать всплывающее окно на как сайте https://uwriterpro.com при hovere на логотип. Почему не применяется стили и как оставить окно popup видимым при наведении на него, а после ухода фокуса скрывать. Пробовал через js - видимо кривые костыли.

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
}
.logo img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
.logo:hover + .popup{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #808080;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.popup-active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.popup:hover {
 visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
      <img src="https://mobile-review.com/articles/2019/image/echo-43/scr/10.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo__img" />
    </a>
    <div class="popup">
      <div class="popup__title">Popup title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вопросы только для вопросов. Если проблема решена, надо опубликовать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил проблему добавив + к селектору

```
.logo:hover + .popup{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```